# Checking rtsp stream on RPI with VLC

Tags: stream, raspberry-pi3, vlc, rtsp

I am new to all of this, so I'm a beginner and do this for my hobby.
I have a Raspberry pi 3+ with the latest updates (stretch and VLC 3.0.6)

My goal is: 
I like to check in Python with VLC to see if a rtsp stream of a Datavideo video encoder is running.

- When the stream is running it should display the stream on the HDMI output
- When the stream is not running it should display that there is no connection via a existing movie file (mp4)

Question: How can I determine in Python if a rtsp stream is running or is not available.

FYI: When I run VLC from the command line with a existing mp4 video file I get a error message: deadlock error prevented using the dummy interface module, but the video file is being displayed correctly on the HDMI output and runs ok.
I can NOT solve this deadlock problem and do not know if this gives major problems when using within Python.
Using OmxPlayer is not an option as it does not recognise the rtsp stream of the DataVideo encoder.

I tried

- to solve the VLC deadlock problem

```py
import subprocess
from time import sleep


while True:
   sleep(3)       
   try:  
      print("start vlc")
      proc=subprocess.call(['cvlc', '/home/pi/Videos/IPdecoder1.mp4'])   
      #playProcess=subprocess.Popen(['cvlc','--play-and-exit','rtsp://192.168.1.114/live'])
      print("after vlc")

   except:
      print("after except")
      Proc=subprocess.Popen(['cvlc','/home/pi/Videos/NoStream1.mp4'])
```

```
Screen errors
[005bf5f8] dummy interface: using the dummy interface module...
[629057b8] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
```